# Ansible - Remove Line

Tags: ansible

Im trying to remove a line from a file. Like so:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Remove Cryptochecksum Line
      lineinfile:
        path: '{{ snapshot_path }}/{{ snapshot_dir }}/configs/{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg'
        state: absent
        regexp: '^Cryptochecksum'
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['asa']
```

The file looks like :

```
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect ip-options
  inspect netbios
  inspect rtsp
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect tftp
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect icmp
  inspect http
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect sip
  inspect skinny
policy-map type inspect dns migrated_dns_map_2
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map type inspect dns migrated_dns_map_1
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
 profile License
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination transport-method http
Cryptochecksum:7e3717e45276a214656372dc510fca38
```

However, it will not remove the line. Am i doing something wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: nope i just get [ok]

Comment: try to run with -vvvv to get more details on the output, I tested with your file,state: absent and regexp: '^Cryptochecksum' .it works fine.

Comment: I get - "msg": "1 line(s) removed".  If the condition doesn't match it would have skipped. So check if the path you have provided is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match.

Try:

`regexp: 'Cryptocheck.*`

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by using `delegate_to: localhost`.